# Ruby on Rails: Rake aborted!

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Estou iniciando no mundo do Rails através do livro *Ruby on Rails - Coloque sua aplicação web nos trilhos*.

Após criar um módulo "usuários" o guia informa para adicionarmos na migração a seguinte linha de comando:

```
add_index :users, :email, :uniqueness => true
```

E posteriormente realizar um "rake db:migrate". Mas ao realizar, o rake é abortado conforme imagem. Alguém poderia ajudar?

[image: console de erro]

Outro detalhe é que quando mudo de `uniqueness` para `unique` a migração funciona. Qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: Um indexe normalmente se utiliza **unique**, ja o **uniqueness** é utilizado para validações antes do    insert por exemplo.

Comment: Uniquess e validação para exclusividade de registro. Unique e o correto ao rodar um rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse o @LuizPicolo, a key `uniqueness` é apenas valida nos validators de ActiveRecord. A key correcta para este caso é `unique`:

```rb
add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
```

Um uso correcto de `uniqueness` seria, por exemplo, no model `User`:

```rb
class User
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```